# Hiding last element using .last()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form id="P" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
    <input class="userImage" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="profileImage" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp">
</form>
```

I have a javascript callback function where I'm trying to hide the last `<input type="file"` and add a new one:

```
$("#P").last(".userImage").hide();
$("#P").append("<input class=\"userImage\" onchange=\"readURL(this);\" type=\"file\""+
   " name=\"profileImage\" accept=\"image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp\">");
```

However everytime it runs it's hiding both the `<input type="file"` elements. I have tried to put a .show() on the last element however then it shows them both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct. Just a simple mistake of how to use [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/).

Use this:

```
$("#P .userImage").last().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try altering your hide() selector as:
`$("#P > .userImage:last-child").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last appearing element, consider using the [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector :

```
// Hide your last image (within your P <form>)
$('#P .userImage:last').hide();
// Append a new one here 
$('#P').append('<input class="userImage" onchange="readURL(this);" ...');
```

Comment: Thanks Rion, I voted this up and it works. I selected the answer i did because it made use of the last() i had initially. Looks like there's some d1cks on this that like to vote down for the fun of it...